# Padded Sketch comprises too many solids (FreeCAD)

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

Under FreeCAD, I sketched on the face of a solid as follows :

[image: sketch]

My problem is, when I use "Pad a selected sketch", the solid created comprises also the original solid.

[image: created solid]

It prevents me, for instance, to get the difference with the first one.

Any idea what may be causing this? How to prevent it?

MyFreeCAD config:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Word size of OS: 64-bit
Word size of FreeCAD: 64-bit
Version: 0.15.4671 (Git)
Branch: releases/FreeCAD-0-15
Hash: 244b3aef360841646cbfe80a1b225c8b39c8380c
Python version: 2.7.11
Qt version: 4.8.7
Coin version: 4.0.0a
OCC version: 6.8.0.oce-0.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got help on [this forum thread](http://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19756)

Using `Part Extrude` instead of `Pad a selected sketch` on the sketch will create an independent solid.

It also turns out that, instead of creating the second solid to do a boolean difference, the good way to "cut" my solid is using the `PartDesign Pocket` tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you just select the face, and pad the face (versus padding the solid), you should not have this problem.